# Woocomerce variations not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce site I have a single product page where i show variations.
before this works perfectly, but then i noticed that it stoped working.
When i select the color of product, the image must change and the price must apear, but its not.
I checked the console and it showed me this error
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2kAd.png)
the file that couse the error is in cache, i deleted th cache and its not helping, the wordpress automaticly recreates the file again

Comment: Without seeing the code we can't help you much

Comment: try reinstalling the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just soloved it, I installed the optimisation plugin, that messed up my js.
After deleting it the problem was gone.